# correct algorithm for buttons to toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons, Edit_1 and Edit_2. By clicking on each one of them, an "expansion" div should appear right below the button which has been clicked.

In the function that I have written, if the display property of the "expansion" div is 'block' under edit_1 and one clicks edit_2, the widow will be displaced under edit_2. But if I click on edit_1 itself, the 'expansion' window will not disappear.

I could easily solve the problem by adding another "expansion" window, but as the 'edit' tags will increase, I need to move this 'one' expansion window among them correctly. I would be grateful if you kindly help me with this;

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="section_1"></div>
    <div id="section_2"></div>
    <button id="edit_1" onClick="edit(1);"></button>
    <button id="edit_2" onClick="edit(2);"></button>
    <div id="expansion"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}

body {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F4F4F2;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family:verdana;}

#container{
    width:820px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    border: dashed 2px blue;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;}

#section_1{
    width:800px;
    height:198px;
    border-top: solid 2px #D24726;
    background-color:#ffcccc;
    top:0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;}

#section_2{
    width:800px;
    height:198px;
    border-top: solid 2px #14826D;
    background-color:#C1FBDE;
    top:200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;}

#edit_1{
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:740px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:4;
    background:url(../images/edit.fw.png) no-repeat;}

#edit_2{
    width:50px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:740px;
    margin-top:215px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:4;
    background:url(../images/edit.fw.png) no-repeat;}

#expansion{
    width:200px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    margin-left:600px;
    top:0px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border-top:solid 2px #D24726;
    display:none;}
```

javascript:

```
function edit(clicked_edit){
    var click=document.getElementById('expansion').style.display;
    if (click=='block'){ /* in any case, if the display property is block, it turns it to none*/
        document.getElementById('expansion').style.display='none';
        }
    var tp=document.getElementById('section_'+clicked_edit).offsetTop;
    document.getElementById('expansion').style.top=tp+'px'; 
    document.getElementById('expansion').style.display='block';
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb5wcrtz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

---

## JQuery Approach

---

you may find great use looking at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/) that uses a nice toggle effect.

the JQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure you could make use of this in your project :)

---

## Javascript Approach

---

Have a look at [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/wx18dsb6/) - it's not using JQuery and should be suitable for you :)

It was found [here](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/hide-layer.php):

---

**Another Approach**

---

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/hefGK/) demo is also another way of showing/hiding the div on press., so there's pleanty of options to choose from! :)

```
<script>
    function showhide()
     {
           var div = document.getElementById("newpost");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: @ MrCoder - Thank you so much but can't use jquery in this project

Comment: @HNML fixed that last link too